# How to read NSDate from Sqlite. Syntax white spot.

Tags: ios, sqlite

I store NSDate in sqlite (DATE format) by automatically inserting date() when new update happens. 
In my object class I have a (NSString*) field to store this value.
In dbAccess (class to store all sqlite query methods) I am reading from db the table and filling object with data from table.

So, my problem is syntax. How to repair it?

Method that's read data from table and fills the object with it

```
...
while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    Item *item=[[Item alloc]init];
    NSDate *dated=(NSDate*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 8);

    //Converting date NSDate to NSString
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
        NSString *date =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:dated]];

    //Trying to input the date into object. The receiving (dated)var is NSString
    item.dated=(date)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:date]:@"";

    [item release];
}
```

Finally getting warning "Incompatible pointer types sending NSString to parameter pointer 'const char'.

How to repair this syntax issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there are reason you're not using CoreData to manage your SQLite database? It takes care of some of the complexities of managing datatypes between the database and objective-C, particularly with storing NSDate objects.

Comment: I am not experienced in such things. At moment I read Core Data book, meanwhile have finished the title of book and what the Core Data about is. Also the reason is that this Lab/First app is database driven application. I want to gain ground in this area as well.

Comment: In that case, I would highly recommend starting with the [Apple Core Data Tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) - there's a bit of a learning curve with it, but it will make your life easier in the long run.

Comment: Thank you for link, but what's about my current question?

Comment: I can't help you with that - but if you have a SQLite database, Core Data is a good abstraction to help deal with some of the complexities of datatypes between the database and your application.

Comment: I'll add a scenario where this is plausible.  I am first-time initializing an app, and want to pre-fill some data in CoreData store.  However, that initial data I am reading from an SQLite db.  So, how do we convert the date from the query into NSDate?  Does it come through as a char * that we can convert to NSString and use a formatter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this turned out to be a very simple solution.  Assuming your dates in SQLite are stored as Date data types, you can query them as strings, and then use a `NSDateFormatter` to convert to `NSDate`, like so:

```
...
const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, strftime('%Y-%m-%d', CreationDate), strftime('%Y-%m-%d', ModificationDate) FROM MyTable";
sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    // Loop through the results
    while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        NSString *creationDateText = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSDate *creationDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:creationDateText];
        // Repeat for ModificationDate
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, 100 years old question that was resolved a long time ago. Anyway thanks for this solution. It works too.